# Pythonic way of executing a loop on a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, loops

This code works but I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way for writing it.

`word_frequency` is a dictionary of lists, e.g.:

```
word_frequency = {'dogs': [1234, 4321], 'are': [9999, 0000], 'fun': [4389, 3234]}

vocab_frequency = [0, 0] # stores the total times all the words used in each class
for word in word_frequency: # that is not the most elegant solution, but it works!
    vocab_frequency[0] += word_frequency[word][0] #negative class
    vocab_frequency[1] += word_frequency[word][1] #positive class
```

Is there a more elegant way of writing this loop?

Comment: Since you're not really using `word` except to look back into `word_frequency` you can iterate over `word_frequency.values()`.

Comment: Lot's of simple and elegant answers here. So... I guess we might say "pythonic" means that the same thing can be done in a myriad of neat ways?

Comment: @Karl python allows us to write very neat and concise code. However if, like me, you learned to program in C, many times you will catch yourself creating resource consuming loops and functions that could be handled in a much more elegant and often more efficient way. https://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html

Comment: Yee, my post was nothing more than a recognition of that. I was trying to point out if you ask a community of python programmers to come up the "the most pythonic way" (a question which I see all the time), what is revealed as pythonic is in fact that python allows for such a compact idiom in multiple ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use numpy for that:

```
import numpy as np

word_frequency = {'dogs': [1234, 4321], 'are': [9999, 0000], 'fun': [4389, 3234]}
vocab_frequency = np.sum(list(word_frequency.values()), axis=0)
```

Comment: Using numpy is like total over kill :P

Comment: Why numpy...its -like Sirtuskottus said- overkill

Comment: True, it's overkill. But depending on the context you might have it imported already.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this is more Pythonic:

```
>>> word_frequency = {'dogs': [1234, 4321], 'are': [9999, 0000], 'fun': [4389, 3234]}
>>> vocab_frequency = [sum(x[0] for x in word_frequency.values()),
                       sum(x[1] for x in word_frequency.values())]
>>> print(vocab_frequency)
[15622, 7555]
```

Alternate solution with `reduce`:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: [x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]], word_frequency.values())
[15622, 7555]
```

Comment: A list comprehension over a for loop is more Pythonic in my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

```
list(map(sum, zip(*word_frequency.values())))
```

Comment: I think this is the shortest possible solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the shortest way to solve this, but hopefully the most comprehensible...

```
word_frequency = {'dogs': [1234, 4321], 'are': [9999, 0000], 'fun': [4389, 3234]}

negative = (v[0] for v in word_frequency.values())
positive = (v[1] for v in word_frequency.values())
vocab_frequency = sum(negative), sum(positive)

print (vocab_frequency)  # (15622, 7555)
```

Though more experienced Pythonistas might rather use zip to unpack the values:

```
negative, positive = zip(*word_frequency.values())
vocab_frequency = sum(negative), sum(positive)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be this:

```
vocab_frequency[0], vocab_frequency[1] = list(sum([word_frequency[elem][i] for elem in word_frequency]) for i in range(2))

print(vocab_frequency[0])
print(vocab_frequency[1])
```

Output:

```
15622
7555
```

Still, one more way to do it, kind of far fetched is this:

```
*vocab_frequency, = list(map(sum,zip(*word_frequency.values())))

print(vocab_frequency)
```

Output:

```
[15622, 7555]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for frequencies in word_frequency.values():
    vocab_frequency = [sum(x) for x in zip(vocab_frequency, frequencies)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert that dictionary to a pandas DataFrame and it would be a lot easier to handle.

```
import pandas as pd
word_frequency = {'dogs': [1234, 4321], 'are': [9999, 0000], 'fun': [4389, 3234]}

#Syntax to create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(word_frequency)

#Result
   dogs   are   fun
0  1234  9999  4389
1  4321     0  3234
```

Now just take the sum of each row and either convert back to list or keep as a dataframe object.

```
#Take sum of each row and convert to list
df = df.sum(axis=1)
df = df.values.tolist()
print(df)

#Output
[15622, 7555]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Single Line Solution:

```
[sum([word_frequency[i][0] for i in word_frequency]),sum([word_frequency[i][1] for i in word_frequency])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n, p in your_dict.vales():
    res[0] += n
    res[1] += p
```

This will be fast and elegant enough.
 Sent from phone.  Sorry for the format.